# How do I archive the contents of the "Conversation History" folder with VBA in Outlook (O365)?

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, skype-for-business

On Outlook, Is it possible to automatically archive the contents of the "Conversation History" folder using VBA?

Analyzing the vba docs I can't find a way to access that folder

Thx

Comment: your question is not clear but to move the contents of a folder to an  archive folder have a look :  [here] (https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm)

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear: I mean moving the contents of the outlook "folder" in which skype conversations are stored

Comment: What have you tried can you share?

Comment: Not at this moment. I've a code to read and managed the items in Inbox and its subfolders, but I can't find a way to access (and manage) to the items of "Conversation History"

Comment: I do not have Skype so have no folder named "Conversation History".  Is this folder listed in the folder pane like other folders?  Inbox is a standard folder and has a "standard" technique for accessing it.  Non-standard folders are easy to access if you know the technique.  Is this what you need to know?

Comment: The folder is listed in the folder pane as 1st level folder (like a "Inbox"). To access to Inbox folder I can use "Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)", but to access to "Conversation History" I don't know the technique.

Answer (score 0):

Any folder can be accessed in multiple ways:

1. Use NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder to access any of the named folders (e.g. Inbox, Drafts, Deleted Items, etc.)
2. Use NameSpace.GetFolderFromID, if you know the EntryID and (optionally) StoreID values for the folder
3. Use Folder.Parent to get the parent folder
4. Use Folder.Folders("FolderName") to get a child folder by name
5. Use Store.GetRootFolder to get the top-level folder for any loaded mailbox or .pst via its relevant Store object

See this example to give you some ideas:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/items-folders-and-stores/enumerate-folders-on-all-stores

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to successfully reference the "Conversation History"

```
Application.GetNamespace("Mapi").DefaultStore.GetRootFolder.Folders("Conversation History")
```