# Outlook Conversation history folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using a code on my work computer to pull in items out of my outlook. The code is to long to retype and I can't log into Stack on the work computer so ill post the line im having problems with and see if its an easy fix before retyping the whole thing. Also the Code works great for the inbox folder. But I have Skype integrated and every conversation I have on Skype goes into the "Conversation History" Folder. But I can not seem to import any of this into excel.

Working Code:

```
Set Folder = OutlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Non Working code:

```
Set Folder = OutlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderConversationHistory)
```

I have tried many different variations and can't get it to work at all. Is the Conversation history not considered a "Folder" or would I have to bring it in in a different way?

Comment: Looks like it might not be considered a folder. [List of default folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) doesn't include it. I found [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65525632/16611259](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65525632/16611259) that might help.

Comment: Yes I found that and tried the "Application.GetNamespace("Mapi").DefaultStore.GetRootFolder.Folders("Conversation History")".  But still getting an error.

Comment: What is the error? What exactly do you need to do with that folder?

Answer (score 0):

This should look through all folders.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub LoopFoldersInStores()

    Dim colStores As Stores
    Dim oStore As Store
    
    Dim oRoot As Folder
    Dim oRootFolders As Folders
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set colStores = Session.Stores
    
    For Each oStore In colStores
    
        Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "oRoot.folderPath: " & oRoot.folderPath
        
        Set oRootFolders = oRoot.Folders
        Debug.Print " objRootFolders.Count: " & oRootFolders.Count

        For i = 1 To oRootFolders.Count
        
            ' Not hidden / hidden
            Debug.Print i; oRootFolders(i)
            
            If oRootFolders(i) = "Conversation History" Then
                Debug.Print " ** Conversation History found **"
                'Set ActiveExplorer.currentFolder = oRootFolders(i)
                ' or
                'oRootFolders(i).Display
                Exit For
            End If
        
        Next

    Next
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```